# Get an error called Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className') className.replace property

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I try create a website and i write a function. Whit This fuction Clicking on the icons will change the active icon class. But I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')` error. I have shared the function below. What do you think is the problem?
This is my function;

```
function PageTransitions(){
    // Button click activa class
    for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++){
        sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace("active-btn", "")
            this.className += 'active-btn'
        }) 
    }
}
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: So clearly `currentBtn[0]` did not find an element. You really should be using classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no button that is selected so you do not find one and it throws an error. So make sure the element exists before using it. And use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
const currentBtn = document.querySelector('.active-btn');
if (currentBtn) currentBtn.classList.remove('active-btn');
this.classList.add('active-btn');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');` returns empty array, because of that your `currentBtn` is empty and `currentBtn[0]` is `undefined`.
This causes `currentBtn[0].className` to fail